# Is it an anti-pattern to have a presentational component inside another presentational component?

Tags: reactjs, redux

Consider the following React+Redux pattern:

```
Container -> Presentational -> Presentational
```

And

```
Container -> Presentational -> Container
```

Are they practical things to do? If not, what should I do and how?

**Real life situation:** I am creating a header component in react, and this is the components structure:

```
App (stores the browser info as props)
  -> Header (passes events and props down to NavigationBar)
    -> NavigationBar (print out all the navigation items if they are not dropdown, else include the Dropdown component)
      -> Dropdown
```

Do I need to separate `Dropdown` component with `navigationBar` component?

Comment: Definitely depends on the situation. Do you have an example of what you're trying to do?

Comment: @nbwoodward check out the updated question

Comment: Generally what I do is if there's one dropdown, then I hardcode it. Then I realize later that I need many dropdowns so I abstract it into it's own component. Remember you can pass children all of a parents props like: `<Dropdown {...props} />` as long as you're careful you're not overwriting other props, etc. The react tutorial on components does this... starts with hardcoding and moves to abstraction.

Comment: @nbwoodward Thanks, I will upvote you if you write your idea as an answer with components structure and related links (if possible)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this concept is covered pretty well in the react tutorial: https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html

When building react components, sometimes it's hard to tell what will be a piece you need once, and what you might want to start recycling later. Luckily react is pretty good at handling this situation. I generally just start off building components and when I realize I want to reuse something, I abstract it into it's own component.

To use your example, I might start out with:

```
const Menu = (props) => {
    return (
       <div id='menu'>
         <div className='menuItem'>
           Home
         </div>
         <div className='menuItem'>
           About
           <div className='dropdown'>
             <div className='subMenuItem'>
               About Me
             </div>
             <div className='subMenuItem'>
               About My Cat
             </div>
           </div>
         </div>
         <div className='menuItem'>
           Contact
         </div>
       </div>
    )
}
```

Maybe I realize I will need several dropdown menus with the same behavior so I just abstract it away into it's own component.

```
const Dropdown = (props) => {
  return ( <div className='dropdown'>
    {props.items.map( item => (
      <div className='subMenuItem'>
        {item}
      </div>
    ))}
  </div>)
}
const Menu = (props) => {
    return (
       <div id='menu'>
         <div className='menuItem'>
           Home
         </div>
         <div className='menuItem'>
           About
           <Dropdown items={['About Me', 'About My Cat']} />
         </div>
         <div className='menuItem'>
           Contact
           <Dropdown items={['Send me email', 'Send me snail mail']} />
         </div>
       </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: Very nice and well structured answer, Thanks a lot

Answer (score -2):

In my opinion ,it is not .For example , window system is putting Presentational  component in another , nest ,and html element is the same . both of them are well designed.

Comment: Sorry, a downvote from me cause this is not what I'm looking for

Comment: @WebDegBrian Maybe reword your question to make it clearer instead of downvoting?